# Can't produce a solid color by specifying directly R, G, B and A

Tags: wpf

I have a converter that determines colors based on some status items. I was going to tweak the colors, opacity etc, but can't even get the colors to match for starters.

Question: Why isn't the outcome of below 2 lines of code equivalent? I am going to use Green as an example. when I run the the first produces a normal solid green, the second is light green with definite opacity/see through:

```
return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green); 

return new SolidColorBrush{Color = new Color{A = 100, B = 0, G = 128, R = 0}};
```

As a test, when I create a Rectangle in Blend and fill it with Green:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Green"
```

I see that R is 0, G is 128, B is 0 ,and A is 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` is not a percentage, it is a byte value like `R`, `G` and `B`. You have to specify `255` for 100% opacity.

Comment: Oh, god! Of course! Thank you very much, I've been tweaking it for 30 minutes now.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the alpha channel input parameter is not in per-cent. You have to set it with a maximum value of 255 like this:

```
return new SolidColorBrush{Color = new Color{A = 255, B = 0, G = 255, R = 0}};
```

Comment: thank you +1, @Clemens answer came first and I accepted it, not sure now why now it says you answered a min earlier, but thank you as well.